# update multiple document with different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb node driver.

the thing is that I have 5 users in my mongodb and they have a key name points, every user has different numbers as point.
I want to to update points of four user and I don't want to call for 4 times to update points of users

```
db.collection('users').update({id:1},{$inc : {points:5}})
```

(id and points will be different for every user)

is there a  way to do in one call?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/bulkWrite/#perform-bulk-operations) to send several at once:

```
db.collection("users").bulkWrite([
 {updateOne:{filter:{id:1},update:{$inc : {points:5}}}},
 {updateOne:{filter:{id:2},update:{$inc : {points:4}}}},
 {updateOne:{filter:{id:3},update:{$inc : {points:3}}}},
 {updateOne:{filter:{id:4},update:{$inc : {points:2}}}}
])
```

Comment: isn't this for mongosh not for node js?

Comment: It should be the same for both.  Note that the `bulkWrite` link above leads to the node.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
db.collection('users').updateMany({id: { $in: [id1, id2, ...] }},{$inc : {points:5}})
```

It matches the documents with the specified id's, and increments the documents according to the update document. I'm currently in no place to test this, but I'm positive it (or something similar) will work

Comment: it will work if I want to increment same no of points for all users but in my case no of points will be diff. for all users.

Comment: Ah I see, then you will have to do with different update calls, or use bulkWrite as Joe suggested